# iTextSharp - How to PDFLayer to Bitmap?

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext

I have a PDF file which has one page with multiple layers.
I have decided to use iTextSharp to parse the pdf file and below is the code I retrieve the layers.

```
string tempOutputFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
Dictionary<string, PdfLayer> layers;

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader( path );

PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper( pdfReader, new System.IO.FileStream( tempOutputFile, System.IO.FileMode.Create ) );

layers = pdfStamper.GetPdfLayers();

pdfStamper.Close();
pdfReader.Close();
```

As a result, I could get a list of PDFLayer objects. But I can hardly find a way to convert it to Bitmap or RGBA/BGRA data. Can anyone please give me a tip for getting an image object from PDFLayer?

-----------------------Added----------------------

Now I am trying to save pdf files for each layer (OCG).

```
    public static void CreatePDF( string fileName, string destinationFolder )
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader( fileName );
        PdfDictionary ocProps = reader.Catalog.GetAsDict( PdfName.OCPROPERTIES );
        PdfDictionary occd = ocProps.GetAsDict( PdfName.D );
        PdfArray order = occd.GetAsArray( PdfName.ORDER );

        List<PdfObject> layers = new List<PdfObject>();
        for( int i = 0; i < order.Size; i++ ) 
        {
            layers.Add( order[ i ] );
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < layers.Count; i++ )
        {
            order.Remove( 0 );
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < layers.Count; i++ )
        {
            order.Add( layers[ i ] );
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper( reader, new System.IO.FileStream( destinationFolder + "\\test" + i + ".pdf", System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew ) );

            stamper.Close();
            order.Remove( 0 );
        }



        reader.Close();

    }
```

The created pdf contains only one layer each. But it has a background of whole original pdf so it's pretty much the same as the original pdf. **How can I remove the background?**

Also, in the second loop of creating test1.pdf, an error is thrown as **iTextSharp.text.DocumentException: 'The original document was reused. Read it again from file.'** How can I avoid this error instead of reopening the original pdf file for each time?

Answer (score 1):

itext is a library for pdf creation and manipulation but it does not feature export of pages or parts thereof (like layers) as images.

Actually one could try and implement that functionality based on itext's parser framework. That framework already provides the functionality to walk the instruction stream and always keep the current graphics state available. Thus, all that remains is to translate each drawing instruction to some operation on a target bitmap.

One should not underestimate this, though, as the pdf instructions have a large degree of flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can't I even make a pdf with selected layers?

Comment: Bruno Lowagie has created an utility for iText that allows removing selected OCGs ("Optional Content Groups", the official name for the layers). Thus, if all content of your PDFs is in some layer, you can use that utility for exporting a given layer selection.

Comment: I made some changes on my code and added more texts in the question. Please take a look  @BrunoLowagie